# Graylog not resolving hostname

Tags: linux, dns, ip, centos, graylog2

I have a Graylog server that is showing IP addresses for 2 servers instead of Hostnames.  It is showing the correct hostnames for the other servers.  I have already confirmed DNS is correct.  Any ideas on why GL would show IP instead of host name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue.  It was a matter of creating reverse lookup entries in DNS.  Originally I only set forward lookup entries.  Then delete the host in Graylog and restart rsync.  Then you can issue logger -p user.err to create a log.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

try using the GELF inputs, and the add-on "graylog-collector". It woll not only show the correct username, but also give you all the details about your logs